# Quotes Required in Google Script Function Parameters?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Running into a bit of a weird issue here. I'm still learning the ins and outs of writing functions for Google Apps, and my first real project is a "shipping dashboard" - basically, a spreadsheet where I can take a tracking number from UPS, FedEx, etc., and from it parse the carrier, generate a tracking link, that type of thing. I'm trying to set it up as a function where I can set the type of data being requested (say, carrier), a tracking number, and have it return said information. Here's where I'm at right now:

```
function trackingData(infoType,trackingNumber) {

  //Regex for various carrier's tracking numbers.
  var upsValue = /\b(1Z ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]{2} ?[0-9A-Z]{4} ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]|[\dT]\d\d\d ?\d\d\d\d ?\d\d\d)\b/i;
  var fedexValue = /(\b96\d{20}\b)|(\b\d{15}\b)|(\b\d{12}\b)/;
  var uspsValue = /\b(91\d\d ?\d\d\d\d ?\d\d\d\d ?\d\d\d\d ?\d\d\d\d ?\d\d|91\d\d ?\d\d\d\d ?\d\d\d\d ?\d\d\d\d ?\d\d\d\d)\b/i;

  //First option: we want to know the carrier we're shipping with.
  if (infoType == 'carrier') {

    if (upsValue.test(trackingNumber)) {
      return 'UPS';
    }
    else if (fedexValue.test(trackingNumber)) {
      return 'FedEx';
    }
    else if (uspsValue.test(trackingNumber)) {
      return 'USPS';
    }
    else return null;
  }
```

The issue comes when passing a value for infoType - if I reference a cell, or set each infoType as a variable and put in a value directly when calling the formula it works just fine. However, if I call it by putting in a cell:

```
=infoType(carrier,trackingNumber)
```

I get:

```
error: Unknown range name carrier
```

The weird thing is it DOES work if I call it with:

```
=infoType("carrier",trackingNumber)
```

(note the quotes around "carrier").

I've looked all over the place to find a solution to keep from having to put the quotes around the formula when it is called but so far haven't had any luck. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: the quotes arround the value indicate it's a chunk of text (aka string). if it doesn't have that delineation the parser thinks its either a variable or some other identifier. I think you are stuck with adding the quotes.

Comment: what happens if you do: `carrier = "carrier"; infoType(carrier,trackingNumber);`?

Comment: @Orangepill - The part that's throwing me off is that it works just fine if it's referencing another cell (rather than manually entering carrier as part of the function). At this point I'm assuming it'll be a workaround in the function, just not sure how to best do that.

Comment: @dave - I mistyped; I'm using =trackingData(infoType,trackingNumber) in the cell. I've tried that solution though, both locally and globally, but it still throws the same error.

Comment: you could probably set carrier as the contents of a cell and reference it by name in the functions.

Comment: Yeah that should work is a cell somewhere lets call if F12 type the text carrier in there .  then for your formula change to `=trackingData($F$12, trackingNumber);`  Then you can just copy paste that SOB down a column.

Comment: @Orangepill - that's what I've done and it does work; I'd just prefer to not have to do that for the sake of simplicity (I'm eventually hoping to use this for some stuff at work, and if I'm going to do a cell reference I'd just as soon stick with quotes when calling the function for the benefit of the people who will also be using it)

Comment: makes sense. Might also make for a better user experience if you had a separate `getCarrier`, `getTrackingLink`, function too... just for simplicity.

Comment: @Orangepill that's what I actually started with and wanted to try and combine into one function since to me that's simplest for me. But then again I occasionally need the reminder that my brain doesn't work like most end users' :)

Answer (score 1):

> error: Unknown range name carrier

That error message is due to the way that the Spreadsheet is interpreting the function arguments.

A function parameter is either a reference or a data element (number, date, string). References can be to a single cell (`A1`) or range (`A1..A23`), to a range on a different sheet (`Sheet2!A1`), or a named range. When you entered `carrier` without quotes, it was interpreted as a named range. Read [Named and protected ranges](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/63175?hl=en) if you're interested.

Here's a little hint from the preamble text with the [Google spreadsheets function list](https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273?hl=en&ref_topic=1361471):

> ... don't forget to add quotation marks around all function components made of alphabetic characters that aren't referring to cells or columns.

Summary - if you want an argument to be passed as a string, put quotes on it.